# How do I check if I established a Wifip2p connection with another device

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct

So I have managed to establish a wifip2p connection with another device. Now I want to do so that my performSearch method only runs if I am not connceted with another device when my onResume() runs in WiFiDirectActivity. How do I do that? Is there a way to write something like¨

```
   if (I am not connected with p2p) {
        performSearch();
 }
```

in the onResume()? This is my code right now

```
public class WiFiDirectActivity extends Activity implements WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener, DeviceListFragment.DeviceActionListener
...

public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    receiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel, this);
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    performSearch();

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: There is a `manager.requestPeers()` method that provides access to `Collection<WifiP2pDevice>`. Every `WifiP2pDevice` has `status`, which can be `AVAILABLE`, `CONNECTED`, etc. Unfortunately, it does look like you can't really do some blocking operation inside `onResume`, because everything handled with callbacks. Alternatively, you can use `WifiP2pGroup` if you know it, and it'll provide similar data to you.